# python cannot connect hiveserver2

Tags: python, hive

I have tried use the example on https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Setting+Up+HiveServer2
but gets the following errors:

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py:1031: UserWarning: /home/dsnadmin/.python-eggs is writable by group/others and vulnerable to attack when used with get_resource_filename. Consider a more secure location (set with .set_extraction_path or the PYTHON_EGG_CACHE environment variable).
  warnings.warn(msg, UserWarning)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hs2.py", line 8, in <module>
    database='default') as conn:
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pyhs2/__init__.py", line 7, in connect
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pyhs2/connections.py", line 46, in __init__
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pyhs2/cloudera/thrift_sasl.py", line 66, in open
thrift.transport.TTransport.TTransportException: Could not start SASL: Error in sasl_client_start (-4) SASL(-4): no mechanism available: No worthy mechs found
```

Here is the hive log:

```
ERROR [HiveServer2-Handler-Pool: Thread-31]: server.TThreadPoolServer (TThreadPoolServer.java:run(296)) - Error occurred during processing of message.
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslTransportException: No data or no sasl data in the stream
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslServerTransport$Factory.getTransport(TSaslServerTransport.java:219)
        at org.apache.thrift.server.TThreadPoolServer$WorkerProcess.run(TThreadPoolServer.java:268)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslTransportException: No data or no sasl data in the stream
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslTransport.open(TSaslTransport.java:328)
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslServerTransport.open(TSaslServerTransport.java:41)
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslServerTransport$Factory.getTransport(TSaslServerTransport.java:216)
```

Does anyone can help solve the problem? Thank you very much.
OS version: **Ubuntu 14.04.1**
Hive version: apache-hive-1.2.0
SASL version: sasl-0.1.3
Thrift version: thrift-0.9.1

Comment: Is your HiveServer2 Kerberized, or in a secured cluster?

Comment: In hive-site.xml, I have set <name>hive.server2.authentication</name><value>NONE</value>

Comment: Is it just the one machine you can't connect-from, or all machines?

Comment: I solved an issue like yours setting authentication to NOSASL.

Answer (score 29):

You are missing some dependencies, make sure you install `cyrus-sasl-devel` and `cyrus-sasl-gssapi`:

On an RHEL-based distro:

`sudo yum install cyrus-sasl-devel cyrus-sasl-gssapi cyrus-sasl-md5 cyrus-sasl-plain`

... or on a Debian-based distro:

`sudo apt-get install sasl2-bin libsasl2-2 libsasl2-dev libsasl2-modules`

Per @KenKennedy, also add the `libsasl2-modules-gssapi-mit` package if using GSSAPI for authentication.

Comment: However, for the Ubuntu servers, they have no `cyrus-sasl-devel` and `cyrus-sasl-gssapi`. I just find and install some likely packages: `sasl2-bin`, `libsasl2-2`, `libsasl2-dev`

Comment: Thanks, added package details for two distro package types. If this now looks correct feel free to accept that answer.

Comment: Sorry for that, after installed these packages,  the errors still exist...Is pyhs2 lib for python to connect hiveserver2 only available for RHEL-based distro?

Comment: Should install from pip, does it not? `sudo pip install pyhs2`

Comment: So you are all-set then?

Comment: Yes..any suggestions?

Comment: All the prerequisites are listed [here](https://github.com/cloudera/hue#development-prerequisites) - can you check each one off?

Comment: Thank you, all of these packages are installed, but it still has the same errors....

Comment: Try `libsasl2-modules`.

Comment: Thank you, installed but the same result.

Comment: Additionally, add the libsasl2-modules-gssapi-mit package if using GSSAPI for authentication.

Answer (score 3):

1 In hive-site.xml, set configuration as below:

```
<property>
   <name>hive.server2.authentication</name>
   <value>NOSASL</value>
</property>
```

2 pyhs2 program codes changes as below:

```
with pyhs2.connect(host='localhost',
                   port=10000,
                   authMechanism="NOSASL",
                   user='user',
                   password='password',
                   database='default') as conn:
```

**Please note that username and password cannot be empty, add any username and password when connects to pyhs2**

Answer (score 2):

Setting up following environment variable worked for me:

```
SASL_PATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sasl2
```

This is for Ubuntu

Comment: in general you want to use `` to surround your code, like `some_code`, to improve readability

Answer (score 0):

The above answers don't work in my case, I've also tried others.
Finally, I've solved my problem (no idea if it works for you).

Just execute

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib64:/usr/local/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

before running your script.

My original `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is `/usr/local/lib:/usr/lib64`