# How can I connect to Impala using a keytab?

Tags: python, kerberos, impala, keytab

I am trying to establish a connection to the impala database through a Python script using a keytab instead the normal user/password combination, but am unable to find any tutorials online whatsoever, the code I am currently using is:

```py
conn = connect(host=impala_host, port=impala_port, use_ssl=True, auth_mechanism="PLAIN", user=username, password=pwd, database=impala_db)
cursor = conn.cursor()
```

However, I want to connect using keytab instead of my password.

Comment: Please tell when you have tried already. your question doesnt look so informative.

Comment: I have updated the description now

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are trying to use that library: https://github.com/cloudera/impyla

Please have a look at **Usage** section in README.md there:

```
from impala.dbapi import connect
conn = connect(host='my.host.com', port=21050)
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM mytable LIMIT 100')
print cursor.description  # prints the result set's schema
results = cursor.fetchall()
...
...
```

Comment: The above code works fine, what i am trying is to replace the password section with a keytab file so that i don't have to connect by hardcoding in my password

Comment: @AshishKumarSingh maybe you could find something useful here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34977562/connect-to-impala-using-impyla-client-with-kerberos-auth