# Can't connect to Hiveserver2 using impyla

Tags: python, hive, impyla

Could somebody help me solve the issue below on Windows 10?

Here is a python code I have:

```
from impala.dbapi import connect
from contextlib import closing

if __name__ == '__main__':

    with closing(connect(host='host_name_with_hiveserver2',
                 port=10000,
                 database='databasename',
                 user='username',
                 password='password',
                 auth_mechanism='PLAIN')) as conn:
        cursor = conn.cursor()
```

**A list of installed Python packages:**

- bitarray==0.8.1
- impyla==0.14.0
- sasl==0.2.1
- six==1.10.0
- thrift==0.9.3
- thrift-sasl==0.2.1

**Versions:**

- OS Version:  Microsoft Windows 10 (64-bit)
- DBMS Version:    1.2.1.2.3.6.0-3796 Apache Hive

**Traceback:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/vinokur/projects/python/hive_connect/main.py", line 11, in <module>
    auth_mechanism='PLAIN')) as conn:
  File "D:\vinokur\projects\python\virtual_envs\pip_impyla\lib\site-packages\impala\dbapi.py", line 147, in connect
    auth_mechanism=auth_mechanism)
  File "D:\vinokur\projects\python\virtual_envs\pip_impyla\lib\site-packages\impala\hiveserver2.py", line 758, in connect
    transport.open()
  File "D:\vinokur\projects\python\virtual_envs\pip_impyla\lib\site-packages\thrift_sasl\__init__.py", line 72, in open
    message=("Could not start SASL: %s" % self.sasl.getError()))
thrift.transport.TTransport.TTransportException: Could not start SASL: Error in sasl_client_start (-4) SASL(-4): no mechanism available: Unable to find a callback: 2
```

I was able to run this code successfully on Linux Ubuntu 16.04 following instructions from [python cannot connect hiveserver2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30705576/python-cannot-connect-hiveserver2) ticket.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you get any solution to this? I´m having the same problem.