# how to use pyhive in lambda function?

Tags: amazon-web-services, hive, pyhive

I've wrote a function that is using pyhive to read from Hive. Running it locally it works fine. However when trying to use lambda function I got the error: 
**"Could not start SASL: b'Error in sasl_client_start (-4) SASL(-4): no mechanism available: No worthy mechs found'"**

I've tried to use the guidelines in this link:
https://github.com/cloudera/impyla/issues/201

However, I wasn't able to use latest command: 
`yum install cyrus-sasl-lib cyrus-sasl-gssapi cyrus-sasl-md5` 
since the system I was using to build is ubuntu that doesn't support the yum function. 
Tried to install those packages (using apt-get): 
sasl2-bin libsasl2-2 libsasl2-dev libsasl2-modules libsasl2-modules-gssapi-mit

like described in:
[python cannot connect hiveserver2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30705576/python-cannot-connect-hiveserver2)
But still no luck. Any ideas?

Thanks,
Nir.

Answer (score 1):

You can follow this [github issue](https://github.com/cloudera/impyla/issues/201). I am able to connect Hive server2 with LDAP authentication using the pyhive library in AWS Lambda with Python 2.7. What I have done to make it work is:

1. Took one EC2 instance or launch container with [AMI used in Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-runtimes.html).
2. Run the following commands to install the required dependencies

   ```
   yum upgrade

   yum install gcc

   yum install gcc-g++

   sudo yum install cyrus-sasl cyrus-sasl-devel cyrus-sasl-ldap #include cyrus-sals dependency for authentication mechanism you are using to connect to hive

   pip install six==1.12.0
   ```
3. Bundle up the `/usr/lib64/sasl2/` to Lambda and set `os.environ['SASL_PATH'] = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), /path/to/sasl2`. Verify if `.so` files are presented on `os.environ['SASL_PATH']` path.
4. My Lambda code looks like:

   ```
   from pyhive import hive
   import logging
   import os
   os.environ['SASL_PATH'] = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'lib/sasl2')
   log = logging.getLogger()
   log.setLevel(logging.INFO)
   log.info('Path: %s',os.environ['SASL_PATH'])
   def lambda_handler(event, context):
       cursor = hive.connect(host='hiveServer2Ip', port=10000, username='userName', auth='LDAP',password='password').cursor()
       SHOW_TABLE_QUERY = "show tables"
       cursor.execute(SHOW_TABLE_QUERY)
       tables = cursor.fetchall()
       log.info('tables: %s', tables)
       log.info('done')
   ```